React Native Modal not Appearing After Verification Success in Sign Up Flow
I’m developing a sign-up screen in my React Native app where I’m using react-native-modal to show two different modals:

A modal for email verification, which appears after the user initiates the sign-up.
A success modal, which should appear once the email verification is completed.

The verification modal works as expected, but the success modal does not appear when verification is successful. I’ve tried triggering it using the onModalHide event, but it’s not showing up.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
const [showSuccessModal, setShowSuccessModal] = useState(false);

// Verification modal
<ReactNativeModal
  isVisible={verification.state === "pending"}
  onModalHide={() => {
    if (verification.state === "success") setShowSuccessModal(true);
  }}
>
  {/* Verification modal content */}
</ReactNativeModal>

// Success modal
<ReactNativeModal isVisible={showSuccessModal}>
  {/* Success modal content */}
</ReactNativeModal>

In this setup:

The verification state is updated to "success" after the email is verified, which I expected would trigger setShowSuccessModal(true) within the onModalHide event of the first modal.
However, after the verification state changes to "success", the success modal still does not show.

I suspect that the onModalHide event may not be executing as expected, or maybe there’s an issue with setting the showSuccessModal state.
Has anyone encountered this issue, or does anyone know how to ensure the success modal appears after the verification modal is hidden?
I tried to set a timeout to wait for the animation to finish before setting showSuccessModal to true
<ReactNativeModal
  isVisible={verification.state === "pending"}
  onModalHide={() => {
    if (verification.state === "success") {
      setTimeout(() => setShowSuccessModal(true), 300); // Задержка в 300 мс для завершения анимации
    }
  }}
>
  {/* Verification modal content */}
</ReactNativeModal>

<ReactNativeModal isVisible={showSuccessModal}>
  {/* Success modal content */}
</ReactNativeModal>

I also tried to combine the windows
<ReactNativeModal isVisible={verification.state === "pending" || showSuccessModal}>
  {verification.state === "pending" ? (
    <View>
      {/* Verification modal content */}
    </View>
  ) : (
    <View>
      {/* Success modal content */}
    </View>
  )}
</ReactNativeModal>

But none of it worked.
Just in case, here is the full code of this screen
import { useSignUp } from "@clerk/clerk-expo";
import { Link, router } from "expo-router";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Alert, Image, ScrollView, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { ReactNativeModal } from "react-native-modal";

import CustomButton from "@/components/CustomButton";
import InputField from "@/components/InputField";
import OAuth from "@/components/OAuth";
import { icons, images } from "@/constants";

const SignUp = () => {
  const { isLoaded, signUp, setActive } = useSignUp();
  const [showSuccessModal, setShowSuccessModal] = useState(false);

  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [verification, setVerification] = useState({
    state: "default",
    error: "",
    code: "",
  });

  const onSignUpPress = async () => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await signUp.create({
        emailAddress: form.email,
        password: form.password,
      });

      await signUp.prepareEmailAddressVerification({ strategy: "email_code" });

      setVerification({
        ...verification,
        state: "pending",
      });
    } catch (err: any) {
      Alert.alert("Error", err.errors[0].longMessage);
    }
  };

  const onPressVerify = async () => {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const completeSignUp = await signUp.attemptEmailAddressVerification({
        code: verification.code,
      });

      if (completeSignUp.status === "complete") {
        await setActive({ session: completeSignUp.createdSessionId });
        setVerification({ ...verification, state: "success" });
      } else {
        setVerification({
          ...verification,
          error: "Verification failed",
          state: "failed",
        });
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      setVerification({
        ...verification,
        error: err.errors[0].longMessage,
        state: "failed",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView className="flex-1 bg-white">
      <View className="flex-1 bg-white">
        <View className="relative w-full h-[250px]">
          <Image source={images.signUpCar} className="z-0 w-full h-[250px]" />
          <Text className="text-2xl text-black font-JakartaSemiBold absolute bottom-5 left-5">
            Create Your Account
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View className="p-5">
          <InputField
            label="Name"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            icon={icons.person}
            value={form.name}
            onChangeText={(value) => setForm({ ...form, name: value })}
          />
          <InputField
            label="Email"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            icon={icons.email}
            textContentType="emailAddress"
            value={form.email}
            onChangeText={(value) => setForm({ ...form, email: value })}
          />
          <InputField
            label="Password"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            icon={icons.lock}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            textContentType="password"
            value={form.password}
            onChangeText={(value) => setForm({ ...form, password: value })}
          />
          <CustomButton
            title="Sign Up"
            onPress={onSignUpPress}
            className="mt-6"
          />
          <OAuth />
          <Link
            href="/sign-in"
            className="text-lg text-center text-general-200 mt-10"
          >
            Already have an account?{" "}
            <Text className="text-primary-500">Log In</Text>
          </Link>
        </View>

        <ReactNativeModal
          isVisible={verification.state === "pending"}
          onModalHide={() => {
            if (verification.state === "success") setShowSuccessModal(true);
          }}
        >
          <View className="bg-white px-7 py-9 rounded-2xl min-h-[300px]">
            <Text className="text-2xl font-JakartaExtraBold mb-2">
              Verification
            </Text>
            <Text className="font-Jakarta mb-5">
              We've sent a verification code to {form.email}
            </Text>
            <InputField
              label="code"
              icon={icons.lock}
              placeholder="1234"
              value={verification.code}
              keyboardType="numeric"
              onChangeText={(code) =>
                setVerification({ ...verification, code })
              }
            />
            {verification.error && (
              <Text className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-1">
                {verification.error}
              </Text>
            )}

            <CustomButton
              title="Verify Email"
              onPress={onPressVerify}
              className="mt-5 bg-success-500"
            />
          </View>
        </ReactNativeModal>

        <ReactNativeModal isVisible={showSuccessModal}>
          <View className="bg-white px-7 py-9 rounded-2xl min-h-[300px]">
            <Image
              source={images.check}
              className="w-[110px] h-[110px] mx-auto my-5"
            />
            <Text className="text-3xl font-JakartaBold text-center">
              Verified
            </Text>
            <Text className="text-base text-gray-400 font-Jakarta text-center mt-2">
              You have successfully verified your account.
            </Text>
            <CustomButton
              title="Browse Home"
              onPress={() => router.replace("/(root)/(tabs)/home")}
              className="mt-5"
            ></CustomButton>
          </View>
        </ReactNativeModal>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
export default SignUp;


First, please close your 1st modal. Then open 2nd modal.
const openSuccessModal = useCallback(() => {
    // closes the verification modal
    setVerificationModalVisible(false);
    // open the success modal
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        setSuccessModalVisible(true);
      },     
      50,
    );

